# Need help getting VPython to work on Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor, vpython

Recently started using the code editor Atom for my Python code. I've been able to get pretty much everything I need to work, except VPython. I've been told that VPython is supported/compatible with Atom, yet it doesn't work.

The main issue is that I'm unable to import the 'visual' module. I've even tried suggested alternatives such as importing 'VPython' or 'vis', and even uninstalled/reinstalled VPython several times in different ways.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Hydrogen package in Atom:
https://atom.io/packages/Hydrogen

Run code and get results inline using Jupyter kernels like IPython, IJulia, and iTorch. It's one of the coolest packages in Atom as it supports inline plot visualizations if that's what you're looking for.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have used Hydrogen from the moment I started using Atom. All of the inline plots work just fine, it's just that when I try to import VPython's 'visual' module Atom says 'no module named visual'. If I instead import the module with name vpython it cannot recognise the basic functions such as 'sphere' or 'box'.

Answer (score 0):

The visual module is part of "classic vpython" which only runs on python 2.7 . If you are using python 3.5.3 or higher then you will need the new VPython 7.x package which is probably what you installed if you followed the instructions at vpython.org . Try running this two lines vpython code.

from vpython import *

box()

If you run these two lines of code you should see a 3D box appear in a webgl canvas in your webbrowser. To write a vpython program use the new syntax and not the old "classic vpython" syntax.

http://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/index.html

Comment: Whenever I run that (in Atom) I get a huge error message that starts with:
EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".